# To prove the interior of a circle is a path connected region

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, connectedness

I'm trying to prove that the interior of a circle is a path connected region.

To prove that, we take two random points $A \neq B$ in the interior of a circle we don't have any point of the circumference in line segment $AB$ and I come to the following result which I can't prove:

Given $\triangle ABC$ and a point $X \in \overline{BC}$ then $AX < \max(b,c)$.

I'm taking a point $P \in \overline{AX}, AP = \max (b,c)$ and trying to use triangular inequality on some triangle, but it is not working so far

Comment: I think I need a background of your problem, because it seems trivial to me your claim (about connectedness of the interior of a circle).

Comment: I'm not using analytic geometry, just the Euclidean. I would like to avoid the wrap theorem. I got the basic theorems that don't really involve circles: similitude, greatest angle is oposite to greatest side, etc.

Comment: It can help to move the point $X$ off the line $BC$ to see the four triangles.  (If I recall correctly, you don't actually care about $BCX$.) This also helps show what algebraic cancellation you want -- a side appearing in two triangles can be algebraically eliminated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of greater angle, greater side [(Euclid I-19)](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI19.html).

Since $\angle AXB + \angle AXC = 180^\circ$, one of $\angle AXB, \angle AXC \ge 90^\circ$.

If $\angle AXB \ge 90^\circ$, it follows that $\angle ABX < 90^\circ$.

By greater angle, greater side, we have $AB > AX$. The case for $\angle AXC \ge 90^\circ$ is similar.

Hence $AX < \max(AB, AC)$.

Answer (score 0):

$AP$ is a minimum at the foot $D$ of the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. It's a monotonic function of $P$ on each of the intervals $BD$, $CD$.

In general, it's easy to prove that any convex set is path connected. That's a stronger property than connectedness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness .

Comment: yeah, sorry I mean path connected gonna edit